# How exactly does the MouseListener API work at the fundamental level?

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

How does the MouseListener 'know' that an event has occured?

I am trying to make a custom object listener to determine when one object has entered another, a parallel to the `mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}` method. In my case, I have an object 'car' that moves and a stationary 'garage'. I want to code the garage with a VehicleListener interface and events like vehicleEntered. So I am interested in how java fundamentally interacts with mouse.

Theoretically, I want to have some code that looks like this:

```
public class Garage implements VehicleListener{
    int x,y;
    public Garage(){
        x = some_x;
        y = some_y;
        addVehicleListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void vehicleEntered(VehicleEvent e):{
        System.out.println("A car has entered the garage");
    }
}

public interface VehicleListener extends EventListener{
    public void vehicleEntered(VehicleEvent e);
}

public class VehicleEvent extends EventObject{
    // EventHandling code
}
```

I have considered performing checks every time a car moves, but that solution could be problematic with many instances of cars and garages.

Edit: Is writing a collision engine the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if anybody can explain you the fundamentals of the mouse listener in java code and if someone can, not sure if it's helpful. Maybe try looking into how collision detection is implemented in games - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection might be a start and explains that for performance games usually implement a broad phase and a narrow phase and also mentions various data structures such as Quad Trees, R-Trees or a Spacial Hashmap can be used.

Comment: @schneida I am familiar with collision detection, which I will be implementing if no solutions come up. The reason I asked this is because the basic MouseListener appears on the surface to not be tracking movement (of which is done with MouseMotionListener), so I suspect that there may be a more fundamental way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to react to mouse and keyboard events, and to display graphical output,  Java integrates with the native [window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system).

Here's a high level overview:

When the user moves the mouse or types on the keyboard, it generates hardware interrupts (or other signals - the exact details don't matter) in the operating system. The operating system makes these events available to a special program called the window system. The window system decides what is shown on the screen: it provides a way for other applications to create "windows" where they can display a graphical user interface. It also provides a way for the applications to be notified of button presses and mouse movements.

Java hooks into the native window system just like any other application with a GUI. When it receives keyboard and mouse events, it translates them into Java event objects. Part of this process is finding the "source" component based on information in the event, such as mouse coordinates. Then it runs the appropriate event listeners registered in the source component and in its parents.

Mouse events originate from hardware. "Moving" objects of your own by changing a few numbers does not generate any events at all. You need to implement a collision detection algorithm that generates events, or use a library that does it for you.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. Thank you for your insights.